C# Maui - Implement Commands on list of check boxes
I have a simple application with a button that adds entries to a CollectionView, each entry of data type "Person" has a CheckBox and a label.
The problem (i think) is that i'm trying to implement the command behaviour on the checkboxes. This command is implemented in the ViewModel.
Whenever i add a new Person, the debugger always breaks here:
enter image description here
Here is my View:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiAppCheckBoxExample.MainPage"
             xmlns:model="clr-namespace:MauiAppCheckBoxExample.Model"
             xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:MauiAppCheckBoxExample.ViewModel"
             xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
             x:DataType="viewmodel:MainPageViewModel">

    <Grid
        RowDefinitions="*,50">
    <CollectionView
            x:Name ="myCollectionView"
            ItemsSource="{Binding People}"
            SelectionMode="Single"
        Grid.Row="0">


        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate EnableViewState ="false">
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Person">
                <Grid
                        ColumnDefinitions="50,*">

                        <CheckBox
                            x:Name="WholeNameCheckbox"
                              IsChecked="{Binding SportingFan, Mode =TwoWay}"
                              HorizontalOptions="Center">
                            <CheckBox.Behaviors>
                                <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior
                                EventName="CheckedChanged"
                                Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodel:MainPageViewModel}}, Path = CheckBoxCheckedCommand}"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding IsChecked, Source={x:Reference WholeNameCheckbox}}"/>

                            </CheckBox.Behaviors>
                        </CheckBox>

                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
                               Padding="10"
                               Grid.Column="1"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>

        <Button Grid.Row="1"
                Text="Click Me"
                Command="{Binding AddPeopleCommand}"/>

    </Grid>
</ContentPage>

The ViewModel:
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
using MauiAppCheckBoxExample.Model;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MauiAppCheckBoxExample.ViewModel
{
    public partial class MainPageViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Person> People { get; }
        public MainPageViewModel()
        { 

            People = new();

        }

        [RelayCommand]
        public async Task OnCheckBoxCheckedAsync(bool value)
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);
        }

        [RelayCommand]
        public void AddPeople()
        {
            Person p = new Person();
            p.Name = "Valentyna";
            p.SportingFan = false;
            People.Add(p);

            p = new Person();
            p.Name = "Gil";
            p.SportingFan = false;
            People.Add(p);
        }
    }
}

And the model:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MauiAppCheckBoxExample.Model
{
    public class Person
    {
        public string? Name { get; set; }
        public bool SportingFan { get; set; }


    }
}

Can you guys pls help a new guy coding with maui? >.<

what is the specific exception, and which line causes it?

In your XAML, you have the command as CheckBoxCheckedCommand. In the ViewModel you have a relay command called OnCheckBoxCheckedAsync.
I don't believe you need the word On at the beginning. I'm sure if Async is adding anything either. I'd expect the relay command name to be 'CheckBoxChecked` or similar.

@Jason The exception is System.InvalidOperationException: 'Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.', in ObservableCollection.cs, on method "OnCollectionChanged". I have added right now an image with the exception.

@tonyedwardspz hi still have the same exception, but what you pointed out was definitely a mistake,thank you!

which line of YOUR code causes the exception?

@Jason On "People.Add(p);" in MainPageViewModel

Just found an answer, the implementation of command now looks like this:                                 Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference Page}, Path=BindingContext.CheckBoxCheckedCommand}"
Thank you all for the time lost! :)

Nice work @GuilhermeGil. If you put your solution into an answer and accept it, you'll help someone in the future with a similar problem

Hi @GuilhermeGil, thanks for your support and feedback for Maui. As a summary, I will post an answer so that it will help others who have similar problems. :)

Yes, the usage of  Relative bindings for the toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior of CheckBox is not right.
We could just replace the following code:
 Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodel:MainPageViewModel}}, Path = CheckBoxCheckedCommand}"

with:
Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference page}, Path=BindingContext.CheckBoxCheckedCommand}"

Note: The page is the property of current page:
 x:Name="page"

For more information about Relative bindings, you can check document: Relative bindings.
